# react-native app is not running - splash screen showing

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a react-native app in VS Code. The app is running fine in the browser with expo. Generated a keystore file and created an .apk with **gradlew assembleRelease**.

The .apk can be installed on my Android tablet. But after starting the app, it is not running and the splash screen is shown (see image below).

The SDK version on the tablet (30) is higher than the minSdkVersion (21) of the app.

Also added `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />` to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

[image: Text]

Code is as follows.

index.js:

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App4 from './App4';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App4);
```

App4.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import List from './List.js'

const App = () => {
   return (
      <List />
   )
}
export default App
```

List.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'
   
class List extends Component {
   state = {
      products: []
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.GetAllProducts();
   }

   GetAllProducts() {
      //fetch("http://192.168.2.14:3000/getallproducts")
      fetch("https://categoriesexpress444.herokuapp.com/getallproducts")
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(jsonresult => {
            this.setState({
                  products: jsonresult
            });
            console.log(this.state.products);
         });
   }

   getsrcPath(string) { // this function distinguishes between images in UserImages folder and images on Cloudinary
      var firstChar = string.charAt(0);
      if (firstChar == '~') { // image is in UserImages folder and item.picture path starts wih ~/UserImages/
         return string.substring(1, string.length);
      }
      else { // image is at Cloudinary and item.picture starts with http://
         return string;
      }
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            {
               this.state.products.map((item, index) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                     key = {item.id}
                     style = {styles.container}>
                     <Text style = {styles.text}>{item.productname}</Text>
                     <Text>{item.description}</Text>
                     <Text>€ {item.price}</Text>
                     <img src={this.getsrcPath(item.picture)} />
                     <Text style = {styles.text}>
                        {item.name}
                     </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
               ))
            }
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default List

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   container: {
      padding: 10,
      marginTop: 3,
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      cursor: 'none'
   },
   text: {
      color: '#4f603c'
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo to create react native app then
you have to build an app over the expo using this command

`expo build:adroid` or `expo build:ios`

once the build will successfully create you will get one URL then you can use the URL to install the app on your device.

If you are using react-native-cli to create react native app then
you have to build an app over the expo using this command

`./gradlew assembleRelease or ./gradlew assembleDebug` in MacOs

Comment: I am getting this message: expo build:android will be discontinued on January 4, 2023. Recommended is eas build. So I generated an eas release build, scanned QR code and installed the app on the Android device, but still the same splash screen showing...

Comment: thank you @Mobygo ,can you please give some example or any demo code, so i can check and try to resolve